# What is an appropriate sequence to generate a preview with XeLaTex?

Tags: xetex

I have used `report` class to compose my article, which includes .eps figures. I want to use XeLaTex to generate a preview. But after compiling with XeLaTex, it gives me only a pdf without an opened preview when it has finished. I also noted that in the pdf file, the citation for equation and reference are marked as question marked? What is the correct order to compile? Thanks!

Comment: If there are question marks in the citations, this can have two reasons. Either your reference is undefined, or you have only compiled once and the correct citations appear after the second run. Of course, you may have to run `bibtex` in between if you are using this tool.

Comment: One could say it is basically the same as with pdflatex. You just change the engine. So if you ran pdflatex->bibtex->pdflatex->pdflatex beforehand you will have to run xelatex->bibtex->xelatex->xelatex now.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with “preview”? LaTeX will only generate the PDF. A preview may be displayed in your LaTeX editor, but this is actually a feature of this editor and depends on what editor you use.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you. My figures (so many figures) are all .eps format. It seems that it cannot be compiled by pdflatex. Could you give some further suggestion?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thanks for your comment. I used WinEdt 7.0 with MiKTeX editor. By ''preview'', I mean it opens an article file just like that text given by compiling Texify.

Comment: Hi @marmot Thank you. I am sure that my references are well defined. By XeLaTex->Bibitex-XeLaTex, I can generate a pdf with correct references. But I still cannot get an opened file immediately after compiling, by clicking a position on which I can go to that position in WinEdt to revise the file. This is what I want.

Comment: @jsxs It is also possible to use eps figures with pdflatex, this works by converting the files automatically to pdf. Depending on your setup it might work without changing anything (just put `\includegraphics{myfile.eps}`) or with adding `\usepackage{epstopdf}` and running with shell-escape or write18 enabled.